# vi needs two <enter> keystrokes instead of one

Tags: vim, vi, vimrc

If I want to open a file using "vi", it needs two `<enter>` keystrokes instead of one.

Any idea, how to fix it?

Just few hours back it was working perfectly.  I have been searching on the net for the solution but couldn't find any.

Comment: Just to clarify when you in your shell and type `vi filename.txt<enter>` nothing happens until you press `<enter>` again?

Comment: @DavidKing, just the cursor goes down to the next line after the first  `<enter>`.

Comment: That sounds more like a shell problem than a vi problem.  Does this same thing happen for other commands?  For example, does `less filename.txt` behave the same way?

Comment: The problem is definitely still happening after the reboot? Does it happen in two windows open side by side, or just in one of them?

Comment: Thanks @roaima, You solved my problem by asking that question. Actually I was logged in a remote server. And after seeing that problem I logged out from the server and then reconnected from the same terminal window. I thought it would be equivalent to restarting the computer. Now there is no problem when I connect to the server from a fresh terminal. Thanks for the help and sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: @user22180 please do not say you rebooted a computer if you didn't reboot it. You haven't solved the problem yet, only sidestepped it ready for some other unwary user.

Comment: @roaima, Yeah I understand the mistake I have done, and truly sorry for that. I understand other users will be affected by such misinformation, and will try my best not to make such mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is almost certainly that there is a rogue process attached to the terminal but still accepting input. You can ascertain the process by running

```
ps -ft $(tty)
```

Ignore the shell (often `bash`) and the `ps` command itself. Anything else you can kill (use `kill` or `kill -1`, followed by the numbers in the PID column). If you rerun the `ps` command and still see the rogue commands then repeat the `kill` command but this time go for `kill -9`. DO NOT use the `-9` unless other options have first been tried, and failed.

Example

```
$ ps -ft $(tty)
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
roaima   29949 29948  1 17:43 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
roaima   30019 29949  1 17:44 pts/0    00:00:00 vi
roaima   30021 29949  0 17:44 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ft /dev/pts/0

$ kill -1 30019    # vi is a background process eating input
$ ps -ft ($tty)
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
roaima   29949 29948  1 17:43 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
roaima   30019 29949  1 17:44 pts/0    00:00:00 vi
roaima   30021 29949  0 17:44 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ft /dev/pts/0

$ kill -9 30019
$ ps -ft $(tty)
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
roaima   29949 29948  1 17:43 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
roaima   30021 29949  0 17:44 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ft /dev/pts/0
```